# Enable dialog for non-admin user

Tags: 8, ajax

I'm building some modal pages using the `use-ajax` class plus the `data-dialog-type="modal"` attribute on link tags. It worked great as an admin user, but logging in as a different role(call it `parent`) and the links go directly to the pages.

It's pretty obvious from the sources panel in web inspector that the `parent` role isn't being served the necessary javascript (`dialog.jquery-ui.js, dialog.js, dialog.position.js, etc`).

There's nothing in the permissions that looks like it would limit the javascript added to the page.

I've tried this in my custom theme and in bartik, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple enough, though a little counter-intuitive coming from a Drupal 7 install where everything but the kitchen sink is included.

All I had to do was to inlcude the library in my theme's `.libraries.yml` file;

```
dependencies:
  - core/drupal
  - core/jquery
  - core/jquery.once
  - core/drupal.dialog.ajax
```

This will be more performent than including the entire core javascript system on every page. It was a little confusing since that is the behavior for the admin user.

Comment: you can also include the library in the build array of the modal link, then you load the library only if necessary, that is when the link is rendered: `$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';`,